# Find last not NULL value for each column then group them in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like that:

```
     uid |      name       | gender | age  | date
    -----+-----------------+--------+------+----------
      38 | Danny Little    | NULL   | NULL | 2018/01/01
      38 | NULL            | NULL   |   24 | 2018/01/02
      41 | NULL            | male   |   40 | 2018/01/03
      43 | OfCourseNewUser | female |   13 | 2018/01/04
      38 | NULL            | NULL   |  100 | 2018/01/05
      38 | ADanny          | male   | NULL | 2018/01/06
      38 | ADanny          | NULL   |   99 | 2018/01/07
```

and I'd like to find the latest value for name, gender and age (obviously from three separate rows), where these are not NULL(if there are all null values, then set null), then group by uid ,the result is like this:

```
    uid  |      name       | gender | age
    -----+-----------------+--------+-----
     38  | ADanny          | male   | 99
     41  | NULL            | male   | 40
     43  | OfCourseNewUser | female | 13
```

I just need a query, which could get LAST_VALUE(column,is ignore null) in other databases. But MySQL doesn't support Window Functions.

How can I get this result?

Comment: why uid 38 gender is male and not null? IT should be null, right?

Comment: See the answer i posted

Comment: @JohnWoo of course uid 38 is not null, please look at my post again

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar sorry, not right

Comment: I just need a query, which could get LAST_VALUE(column,is ignore null) in other databases. But MySQL doesn't support Window Functions.

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned your MySQL doesn't support Window Functions. Then, I thought why don't use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead?

Check this out:

```
SELECT u.uid,
       u.name,
       u2.gender,
       u.age,
       u.date
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u2 ON u2.uid = u.uid   AND u.age IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u3 ON u3.uid = u2.uid  AND u2.gender IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY uid, name
HAVING 
    u.date = MAX(u.date)
AND u.uid IS NOT NULL
AND u.age IS NOT NULL
```

OUTPUT

```
| uid |            name | gender | age |       date |
|-----|-----------------|--------|-----|------------|
|  38 |          ADanny |   male |  99 | 2018-01-07 |
|  41 |          (null) |   male |  40 | 2018-01-03 |
|  43 | OfCourseNewUser | female |  13 | 2018-01-04 |
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/454336/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
select * from YourTable where gender!=NULL and age!=NULL order by date desc;
```